# Select * matches where current date bigger than now and current time bigger than now

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Working with dates and times has always been a challenge for me, I have done plenty of research on SE regarding mysql date queries but have not found anything concrete enough to help me with my problem.

Im working on app for work which needs to display all matches which has not expired, **a match expires when the date has passed AND time has passed**.

**Example:**

A match could still be active even though the match day is today providing that the time has not past...I think you get what I mean?

The above is the simple part the hard part is the implementation.

I could go:

`SELECT * FROM matches WHERE match_date >= CURDATE();`

**MY Question(s)**

- How would I modify the above query that it **includes a time function aswell**?
- Would you say the above query regarding DATE is the best / most effective query I can use for what I want to achieve?

Any help / advice appreciated

Comment: Can't you just use `datetime` as column type? That's exactly what represents a day+time... That way you can use `match_time >= NOW()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM matches
WHERE match_date > CURDATE() OR
      ( match_date = CURDATE() and match_time > CURTIME() );
```

Note:  You should really store the date and time in a single field.  Then you could do:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM matches m
WHERE match_datetime >= now();
```

Much simpler.  And more likely to use an index.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `DATE` and `TIME` with the `TIMESTAMP()` function.

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE TIMESTAMP(match_date, match_time) >= NOW()
```

In order to use an index at least for `match_date` you can add a redundant condition `match_date >= CURDATE()`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM matches 
WHERE match_date >= CURDATE()
  AND TIMESTAMP(match_date, match_time) >= NOW()
```

The first condition will ignore everything before today using an index.

As other already mentioned things get easier if you use a DATETIME or a TIMESTAMP column. If you use  MySQL 5.7.6 (or greater), you can also create a [computed/generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) and index it.